# Server Side validation for iOS applications

Tags: ios, validation, jakarta-ee

I have an iOS based app making requests to a Java EE server side component.

We typically do validations on both the client side and the server side for web based applications and I was thinking that we can possibly avoid the server side data validation if we can trust the iOS application.

In other words, does it make sense to simply rely on the data validation done at the iOS app and ignore them on the server side? I am assuming SSL between the iOS app and the Java EE server side here so data cannot be tampered during transit here.

Appreciate comments and thoughts.

Answer (score 2):

You should perform input validation on both sides.

You perform client-side validation to provide quick and direct feedback to the user so they can fill out the input UI easily.

You perform server-side validation so that scr1ptk1dd13 can't create fabricate a request, on his PC, to your server and ruin your party.  I don't think SSL will make any difference here in stopping him from accessing your server unless you are using some sort of certification validation, which you don't appear to be doing.

Comment: Trojanfoe, Thanks. At this point in time, i am not sure whether we will be doing a client side cert validation.